# subgroups of order 2 of $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The number of subgroups of order 2 of $S_4$ is nine?

In fact I have : {1,(12)}, {1,(13)}, {1,(14)}, {1,(23)}, {1,(24)}, {1,(34)}, {1,(12)(34)}, {1,(14)(23)}, {1,(13)(24)}

Comment: Also, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73754/subgroups-of-s-4-isomorphic-to-s-3-and-s-2 contains a more detailed/methodical answer.